# React Native child view not getting 100% width, when parent view has flexDirection ="row

Tags: android, ios, react-native, user-interface, flexbox

```
  <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          padding: 5,
          borderWidth: 1,
          backgroundColor: 'pink',
        }}>
        <Text style={styles.goldenText}>Cancel</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
  <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          padding: 5,
          borderWidth: 1,
          backgroundColor: 'pink',
        }}>
        <Text style={styles.goldenText}>Cancel</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
```

My parent view has flexDirection="row". I need my child components to take the entire width of parent view dynamically.
ie, if there are 3 child components i need it to be divided equally, in the yellow region without margin between them. Tried width, flex etc
but nothing seems to be working..
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a try by flex: 1 in the parent style.

For Example:

```
<View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue.
After a bit of research I found that , when parent view has flexDirection:"row"
the flex inside the touchableopacity(child component) doesn't works.
I replaced TouchabllOpacity with pressable and now flex gets applied properly.

```
    <View
      style={{
        flexDirection: 'row',
        backgroundColor: 'yellow',
      }}>
      <Pressable
        style={{
          padding: 5,
          borderWidth: 1,
          backgroundColor: 'pink',
          flex: 1,
        }}>
        <Text style={styles.goldenText}>Cancel</Text>
      </Pressable>
      <Pressable
        style={{
          padding: 5,
          borderWidth: 1,
          backgroundColor: 'pink',
          flex: 1,
        }}>
        <Text style={styles.goldenText}>Cancel</Text>
      </Pressable>
      <Pressable
        style={{
          padding: 5,
          borderWidth: 1,
          backgroundColor: 'pink',
          flex: 1,
        }}>
        <Text style={styles.goldenText}>Cancel</Text>
      </Pressable>
    </View>
```

[image]

Comment: There are two differences from the code in the OP - one is Pressable, but the other one is `flex: 1` on children. I believe the latter is actually doing the job.